# crawling in scrapy..not getting result as expected

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

Whatever I have tried
step 1

```
scrapy shell http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx?expandable=0
```

**fount this xpath form Mozilla firebug**

```
sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
```

does not work

```
sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()').extract()[0]
```

does not work

```
sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()').extract()
```

does not work

**Found xpath from chrome**

```
sel.xpath('//div[@id="wrap"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

It is working fine in chrome console but while doing in command the output is `[]`. The result is same in for mozilla xpath also.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox have the tendency to add some DOM elements to the tree. The `tbody` tag is added. Also assuming you are looking for class name `TTRow` in the HTML, you can use the selector path as:

```
In [32]: response.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]//table//tr[@class="TTRow"][3]/td[2]/text()').extract()
Out[32]: [u'DWITIYA']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...but why there is a `u` coming?

Comment: When scrapy extracts an element from a selector it converts it to a `unicode` object. The prefix `u` is to indicate it's a unicode object.

Comment: How can I remove that?...I want `DWITIYA` this only

Comment: @khalid `u` is only information for Python that it has to use unicode string (and IPython shows it to inform you about it). If you print it using `print()` then you will no see this.

Comment: The prefix `u` won't be stored anywhere but if you wanted to convert the `unicode` variable `text` to `ascii` then you can do `text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`. This will ignore all unicode characters. Also please accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: For using scrapy go through the [scrapy docs](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org). It's useful. Since webscraping is a broad topic you will have to explore the field yourself through google.

Comment: @khalid I use Google as tutorial + 
knowledge about HTML, CSS, JavaScript, HTTP, Chrome/Firefox DevTools,

Comment: Thank You...so much